# Pyspark get count in aggregate table

Tags: pyspark

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------------+-----+
| PULocationID| fare|
+-------------+-----+
|            1|    5|
|            1|   15|
|            2|    2|
+-------------+-----+
```

I want to get a table that looks like this:

```
+-------------+----------+------+
| PULocationID| avg_fare | count|
+-------------+----------+------+
|            1|        10|     2|
|            2|         2|     1|
+-------------+----------+------+
```

Here is what I'm trying:

```
result_table = trips.groupBy("PULocationID") \
        .agg(
            {"total_amount": "avg"},
            {"PULocationID": "count"}
    )
```

If I take out the count line, it works fine getting the avg column. But I need to get the count also of how many rows had that particular PULocationID

NOTE: I can't add any other imports other than `pyspark.sql.functions import col`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was so close, I was just formatting it as two dictionaries instead of one.

```
result_table = trips.groupBy("PULocationID") \
        .agg(
            {"total_amount": "avg","PULocationID":"count"}
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

**This should be the working solution for you - use** **`avg()`** and **`count()`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,5),(1,15),(2,2)],[ "PULocationID","fare"])
df.show()
df_group = df.groupBy("PULocationID").agg(F.avg("fare").alias("avg_fare"), F.count("PULocationID").alias("count"))
df_group.show()

**Input**
+------------+----+
|PULocationID|fare|
+------------+----+
|           1|   5|
|           1|  15|
|           2|   2|
+------------+----+

Output
+------------+--------+-----+
|PULocationID|avg_fare|count|
+------------+--------+-----+
|           1|    10.0|    2|
|           2|     2.0|    1|
+------------+--------+-----+
```